# Electrostatic vs Magnetostatic

Tags: electromagnetism

I understand that a straight wire carrying constant current is both electrostatic and magnetostatic. I am trying to look for example where it is electrostatic and not magnetostatic and also example where it is magnetostatic but not electrostatic. Thanks.

Comment: please clarify where you read that " a straight wire carrying constant current is both electrostatic and magnetostatic". current is not static, by definition

Comment: I didn't read that from somewhere. My initial understanding of electrostatic is constant B-field which I realise that it is a necessary but not sufficient condition for electrostatic after discussion with Nyra.

Answer (score 0):

First, A straight wire carrying constant current is not an electrostatic case in a lab frame.

- A current-carrying wire in lab frame: Magnetostatic
- Bunch of stationary charges: Electrostatic
- Stationary charged spin particle: Electrostatic and Magnetostatic (!!!)

Comment: I supposed a bunch of stationary charges is both electrostatic and magnetostatic. Since the charges are not moving, there is no current and zero current is a constant current. My understanding of magnetostatic is constant current. Do you have an example of electrostatic but not magnetostatic?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You are asking for an example where charges are accelerating and charges are stationary.

Comment: Great, so electrostatic imply magnetostatic but not the other way round. Books should mention that. Thanks Young Kindaichi!

Answer (score 0):

i think a wire carrying a current is **not** electrostatic as the [charges are moving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics#:%7E:text=Electrostatics%20is%20a%20branch%20of,attract%20lightweight%20particles%20after%20rubbing.) .

The prefix '-static' refers to stationary things, so an example of electrostatics is a stationary, charged balloon, I don't think it is technically **not** magnetostatic as the magnetic field is a constant, zero, (when the observer/measurer is  stationary, with respect to the balloon).

An example of a magnetostatic system that is not electrostatic is a constant current in a stationary loop of wire, it produces a constant magnetic field and as the charges are moving it isn't electrostatic.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I understand electrostatic wrongly. I thought in electrostatic, the B-field is not changing. The B-field cause by constant current is not changing.

Comment: @GausteinLim agreed, in electrostatic, the B-field isn't changing, but a current isn't in electrostatics as the charges are moving, therefore not stationary. A constant B-field doesn't imply electrostatics, but it is required for electrostatics.

Comment: ok thanks. Constant B-field is a necessary but not sufficient condition for electrostatic. So in electrostatic, the charges are not moving, which imply there is no current. Since zero current is a constant current, can we say that electrostatic imply magnetostatic. My understanding of magnetostatic is constant current.

Comment: @GausteinLim i think so, [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics#Electrostatic_approximation) of the electrostatics Wikipedia page, suggests that in electrostatics, $\nabla \times E =0$ which implies (from maxwells equations) $\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=0$, therefore magnetostatics.

Comment: Great, electrostatic imply magnetostatic. Books should mention that. Thanks Nyra!